# How to use currency and date filter for IOS in Ionic 2?

Tags: ios, angular, ionic2

I am using currency and date filter in my ios ionic 2 app. But It was throwing an error when i open a page in my app. How to fix this issue? Or Is there a way to use currency and date filter in IOS?

The error is:

> Can't find variable: Intl

Comment: what you did? paste code.

Comment: This is my template: <ion-badge color="theme-badge">{{price | currency:'INR':true:'1.0-0'}}</ion-badge>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because it relies on the internalization API, which is not currently available in all browsers ([compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esintl/)).

You can try to use a polyfill for **Intl** like this:

```
npm install --save intl
```

And then, add these imports to your app:

```
import 'intl';
import 'intl/locale-data/jsonp/en';
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help :)